# How can i do efficient search in datagrid view?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using data grid view in my windows form application.in my application i query every time when i need to search data.i wrote search query for text box key down event.my application gets little slower while running application.i have around 2000 rows of data in my table.how can i make my search faster and reduce database load .Is there any option to search data in data grid without database interaction

my code is below

```
private void txtsearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            datagridproduct.Focus();
        }
        string constring = @"Data Source=PC1\WINMANERP;Initial Catalog=Easylife;Integrated Security=True";
        //if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        //{


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Item_Details where Item_Code LIKE '%' + @NM + '%' OR Item_Name LIKE '%' + @NM + '%'  OR Supplier_Name LIKE '%'+@NM+'%' OR Location LIKE '%' + @NM + '%'", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NM", txtsearch.Text);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        datagridproduct.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }



        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once all the items have been loaded in DataGridView, you can search with data grid cell instead of database and set visible property hide of rows which do not match with your search criteria.

```
private void Search(string item)
    {
        TotalRecords = 0;
        List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                //search on 1st row of datagridview
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == item)
                {
                    row.Visible = true;
                    TotalRecords += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        labelTotalRecords.Text = "Total records = " + TotalRecords.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare DataTable in Global and user datatable select method (DataRow[] rows=dt.Select("columnName="+urvalue)); and make iteration according to row or you can use "DataTable dt1=rows.CopyToDataTable(); " datagridproduct.DataSource = dt1;

If you found answer is useful put a like in answer